# Anyone remember a rotary dial adder project from the early 1980s?

Tags: telephone, adder, history

When I was a kid in the early 80s in the US, I remember coming across a published electronics project that involved a rotary dial from a telephone and small lamps, which I think was a simple adder. I have this picture in my mind of a photo in the magazine or book where it was actually constructed out of wood. I also recall that all the parts were specified with Radio Shack part numbers. I also remember that upon going to the local Radio Shack, they had virtually none of the parts (remember, this was the beginning of the long fall for RS).

I'm looking for **that specific project** or **that specific book/magazine**. Not just any project involving a rotary dial or an adder. I've tried all combinations of terms on Google and haven't come up with anything that matches my memory.

Here are my speculations.

- It may have been a project from the 70s, since the 80s saw rotary dials go into the trash.
- I'm also almost positive it used transistors, not tubes.
- And, it used lamps and not LEDs.
- I haven't exhaustively searched Popular Electronics or Radio Electronics, but I can tell you it is not among [the first few years of 80s projects in Radio Electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_projects_published_in_Radio-Electronics_magazine).
- I am also nearly positive it wasn't a Forrest Mims book.

Any pointers?

Comment: A pulse dial can run a counter, and dialing '2-2' would put four pulses out, so the counter would  indicate '4'.  So, the counter and display are possibly a calculator (wire pulses to activate the 'add memory' button, put '1' in memory) or a pedometer.  So, 'calculator' or 'pedometer' might be searchable terms.

Answer (score 2):

There was such a project as part of the 555 timer contest.

Here is are links to the project:
[Alan's Lab: 555 Adding Machine](http://www.vk2zay.net/article/258)
[MINIMALISTIC 555 ADDING MACHINE](http://hackaday.com/2011/05/27/minimalistic-555-adding-machine/)
[555 contest winners](http://makezine.com/2011/04/21/555-contest-winners-announced/)

Comment: That was from 2011, not from the 80s. Still, neat project.

Comment: @Robert B: I'm aware of it, but the project seams to fit your description. So the technical details may be similar. Especially because the 555 timer was already present in the 80th.